# How to understand the speedup in optimization report from icc compiler?

Tags: vectorization, intel, compiler-optimization, simd, icc

environment is:
icc version 19.0.0.117 (gcc version 5.4.0 compatibility)
Intel parallel studio XE cluster edition 2019
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz
Ubuntu 16.04

compiler flags are:
-std=gnu11 -Wall -xHost -xCORE-AVX2 -O2 -fma -qopenmp -qopenmp-simd -qopt-report=5 -qopt-report-phase=all

I use OpenMP simd or intel parama to vectorize my loop to gain the speedup. In the optimization report generated by icc, I usually see the following result:

```
LOOP BEGIN at get_forces.c(3668,3)
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference mon->fricforce[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3669,4) ]
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference mon->vel[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3669,36) ]
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference vel[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3669,51) ]
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference mon->drag[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3671,4) ]
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference mon->vel[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3671,40) ]
   remark #15389: vectorization support: reference vel[n1][d] has unaligned access   [ get_forces.c(3671,57) ]
   remark #15381: vectorization support: unaligned access used inside loop body
   remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 2
   remark #15309: vectorization support: normalized vectorization overhead 0.773
   remark #15300: LOOP WAS VECTORIZED
   remark #15450: unmasked unaligned unit stride loads: 3 
   remark #15451: unmasked unaligned unit stride stores: 2 
   remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
   remark #15476: scalar cost: 21 
   remark #15477: vector cost: 11.000 
   remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 1.050 
   remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
   remark #25456: Number of Array Refs Scalar Replaced In Loop: 1
   remark #25015: Estimate of max trip count of loop=1
LOOP END
```

My question is: 
I do not understand how the speedup is calculated from

```
normalized vectorization overhead 0.773
scalar cost: 21 
vector cost: 11.000
```

Another more extreme and puzzled case could be

```
LOOP BEGIN at get_forces.c(2690,8)
<Distributed chunk3>
   remark #15388: vectorization support: reference q12[j] has aligned access   [ get_forces.c(2694,19) ]
   remark #15388: vectorization support: reference q12[j] has aligned access   [ get_forces.c(2694,26) ]
   remark #15335: loop was not vectorized: vectorization possible but seems inefficient. Use vector always directive or -vec-threshold0 to override 
   remark #15305: vectorization support: vector length 2
   remark #15309: vectorization support: normalized vectorization overhead 1.857
   remark #15448: unmasked aligned unit stride loads: 1 
   remark #15475: --- begin vector cost summary ---
   remark #15476: scalar cost: 7 
   remark #15477: vector cost: 3.500 
   remark #15478: estimated potential speedup: 0.770 
   remark #15488: --- end vector cost summary ---
   remark #25436: completely unrolled by 3  
LOOP END
```

Now, 3.5+1.857=5.357 < 7
So, I could still simd this loop and gain a speedup or I should take the speedup number 0.770 in the report and not simd it?

**How to understand the speedup in optimization report from icc compiler?**

Answer (score 2):

The “scalar cost” means “cost of one iteration of scalar loop”.

The “vector cost” means “cost of one iteration of vectorized loop divided by 
vector_length*unroll_factor”, i.e. cost of somewhat equivalent to one scalar iteration.

The “vectorization overhead” shows normalized (by vector iteration cost) cost of vector initializations/finalizations before/after the loop.

The “estimated potential speedup” is calculated for the whole loop execution. It shows the normalized (by scalar iteration cost) potential gain of vectorized loop execution – including peel, remainder, and main loop for the estimated loop trip count. It can’t be derived explicitly from the scalar and vector cost shown above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. It is clearer now. If this is not to much to ask for, could you make up a simplest pseudo-code example with those cost numbers to demonstrate how these those numbers add up? especially the "overhead" and "speedup" number.